# Why is my isNaN not working?

Tags: javascript

```
if (isNaN(telenum)){
        error = true;
        document.getElementById('telenum').style.background = 'red';
        document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red;'> Only Enter numbers!</span>";

}else if (telenum < 11){
        error = true;
        document.getElementById('telenum').style.background = 'red';
        document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "<span style='color:red;'> Enter a valid number!</span>";

}else{
        document.getElementById('telenum').style.background = 'white';
}
```

When I test this by entering an 11 digit number it doesn't work and it says: Only enter numbers!

Anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Is `telenum` a string, perhaps? Is it evaluating "11" instead of 11? Can you talk more about how you're calling this?

Comment: Please show us the number you're inputting, and the code in which you're inputting it.

Comment: what is the datatype of `telenum`?

Comment: Like carpeliam suspects, you probably need a parseInt somewhere.

Comment: Maybe [`isNaN()` is broken](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)?

Comment: isNaN() of number written as a string returns false so user puts something else in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is how you set **telenum** variable.

You should post that piece of code.

Anyway...

If you have an input field like

```
<input type="text" name="telenum" id="telenum" />
```

The correct way to get the value inside the field is

```
telenum = document.getElementById("telenum").value;
```

---

Note that it doesn't matter if telenum is a string for evaluating with isNaN.

Just try

```
isNaN("123");
```

on the console of your browser. It returns **false**

"123" is a string but contanins a number. So isNaN returns false